# Marketing Cloud: Add field to existing Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I need to add a new field/column to an existing Data Extension.  The data extension is referenced all over the place.  Am I going to mess up any of my existing journeys, automations, queries, imports by adding this new field/column?

What are the "gotchas" I need to know about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with adding a new field to an existing data extension. You should avoid renaming or removing existing fields, as this will come with a risk of messing up queries, personalizations or similar in existing functionality.

If you can't see **Create Attribute** button on the data extension in Contact Builder, you should check the permission for that specific data extension:

[image]

Clicking on **Edit** will show you whether it is allowed for users to create new attributes:

[image]

Once you enable this option, it should be possible to add additional fields.

Comment: I'm missing something: "Contact Builder uses this data extension as part of a data relationship. Perform any necessary edits in Contact Builder."

I go into Contact Builder, find my DE - but there is no "Create Attribute" button.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000356355&type=1

Comment: @SophiaMurphy please see my updated answer

Comment: THANK YOU!  I'm too new and can't upvote your answer.  Feel like an idiot that I didn't see those.